# Parameter class like a class

Tags: java, generics, methods

I want do a GenericDao pass by parameter Entity but I don´t know how to convert Entidad to Object. I tried put `GenericDaoWithOrder<Entidad extends Object>` but does not work.

```
public abstract class GenericDao<Entidad> {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

    public List<Entidad> findAll(Integer start, Integer maxResult) {
        TypedQuery<Entidad> query = em.createNamedQuery(Entidad.class.getCanonicalName() + ".findAll", Entidad.class);            
        query.setFirstResult(start);
        query.setMaxResults(maxResult);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you defined GenericDao? And where are you using Id type field?

Comment: @almasshaikh Why you need how are defined GenericDao? Id is been used in GenericDao

Comment: Is it generic too? You should generalize from parent.

Comment: This is genericDao @almasshaikh

Comment: try <? extends Object>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you've shown, `Entidad` is a parameter, not a class name, so you can't refer to `Entidad.class`.  The usual way to resolve this kind of thing is to pass the `Class` object representing the real class to the constructor of `GenericDao`, e.g.

```
public abstract class GenericDao<E> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private Class<E> clazz;

    protected GenericDao(Class<E> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public List<E> findAll(Integer start, Integer maxResult) {
        TypedQuery<E> query = em.createNamedQuery(clazz.getCanonicalName() + ".findAll", clazz);            
        query.setFirstResult(start);
        query.setMaxResults(maxResult);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

(I've shortened the type parameter name to `E` to make it clearer that it's a parameter rather than the name of a real class).  Concrete subclasses then pass in the relevant `Class`:

```
public class UserDao extends GenericDao<User> {
  public UserDao() {
    super(User.class);
  }
}
```